# Component flashes old data before showing new one?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a countdown component. When I refresh the page, it will flash the old countdown numbers before showing the new one.

```
import React from 'react';
import { intervalToDuration} from "date-fns";

export function App(props) {

  const endDate = "2023-02-26T00:00:00.000Z";
  const now = new Date();
  const end = new Date(endDate);
  
const remaining = intervalToDuration({
    start: now,
    end: end
  })

  return (
    <div className='App'>
    <h1>Time left until anniversary</h1>
      <h1>{remaining.months}</h1>
      <h1>{remaining.days}</h1>
      <h1>{remaining.hours}</h1>
      <h2>Countdown above!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For example, if the countdown was : 5 days and 20 minutes left. And after a moment i refresh the page it will flash 5:20 before showing 4:58.

Comment: You mean when you refresh with the refresh button of the browser or just hot reloading ?

Comment: @Dilshan when i hit the refresh button/click the url and hit enter.